# MySql not updating after UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables, union

I am new with SQL. I have two tables that I want to join using the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM
 (
   SELECT * FROM OPTIONS
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM tmp
 )  AS OPTIONS;
```

Where `OPTIONS` is a table with 300k rows and 55 columns & `tmp` is a table with 300K rows and 55 columns. When I run the query it joins the both tables but when I check `OPTIONS`, it still has 300k rows. How do I replace or update `OPTIONS` so that it has 600k rows & 55 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well you want to insert all rows on the `tmp` table into the `OPTIONS` table. You can do that by:

```
insert into OPTIONS select * from tmp;
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to `INSERT` the rows from `tmp` into `OPTIONS`.

```
INSERT INTO OPTIONS
            SELECT *
                   FROM tmp;
```

Note: You should change the `INSERT` to include the targeted columns and also explicitly have them in the `SELECT`, replacing the `*`. I couldn't do that because you didn't disclose your tables' structure.